# Should I insert and delete record OR insert and update record for LIKE/UNLIKE button? Which one is more cost effective?

Tags: mysql, social-media-like

In a project in which I need to implement like/unlike functionality, I want to know which approach would better than other from performance point of view. If I have to go with insert delete, then what would happen if someone like/unlike it so many times (Then probably most of primary key numbers will be occupied based on like/unlike)?
Does anyone know how social networking sites do it?

EDIT:
My table is as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `junc_user_share_like` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `jusid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `liker` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `when` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `jusid` (`jusid`,`liker`),
 KEY `liker` (`liker`),
 CONSTRAINT `junc_user_share_like_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`liker`) REFERENCES `user` (`uid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `junc_user_share_like_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`jusid`) REFERENCES `junc_user_share` (`jusid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

EDIT 2:
As you said with last updates this is what I've inferred:

```
INSERT INTO likes SET jusid=$jusid, liker=$liker
UPDATE junc_user_share SET likes=likes+1 WHERE id=$id
```

This works great for likes, but what if someone wants to undo his like? Should I delete record from likes? My problem is exactly here? What to do here?

Comment: please provide more detail regarding the question so it is easy to understood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denormalize.

- have a table with the likes and unlikes (**Who** did **what** to **which** item)
- have a `likes` and a `unlikes` field on the items table, both starting with 0

On a like/unlike do (assuming 1=like, 0=unlike)

```
INSERT INTO likes_unlikes SET item=[id of item], user=[id of user], action=[0|1];
UPDATE items SET likes=IF([action]=1,likes+1,likes), unlikes=IF([action]=0,unlikes+1,unlikes) WHERE id=[id of item]
```

A `UNIQUE KEY` on `likes_unlikes(item,user)` gives you uniqueness as a present.

**Edit**

After discussion, if you just have likes, but no dislikes, the situation is even easier:

- only a `likes` table is needed with item and user id
- only a `likes` field is needed on the items table

the queries are now something like

```
INSERT INTO likes SET item=[id of item], user=[id of user];
UPDATE items SET likes=likes+1 WHERE id=[id of item]
```

and for reversal of a like:

```
DELETE FROM likes WHERE item=[id of item] AND user=[id of user];
UPDATE items SET likes=likes-1 WHERE id=[id of item]
```

Comment: I have table with likes and unlikes: who liked which post.

Comment: So you have one part. Implement the second part and you are fine!

Comment: In your approach you have to update two tables. Mine was one table.

Comment: Yep, that's true - one more update for every like/unlike. On the other hand, if you **display** the likes/unlikes, you lose all the joins on the `SELECT`, which gives an enormous speedup, Since I am quite sure, that for every **written** like/unlike you will have hundreds or thousands **reads**, this is a good deal.

Comment: I just show likes there is actually no unlike (unlike: undo your like). My approach is more like G+.

Comment: This makes the situation even easier: drop the `action` and `unlikes` fields and all references to them.

Comment: If it's possible please see the `EDIT 2` part of my question, thanks for your patience.

Comment: Just reverse the statements: `DELETE FROM likes WHERE jusid=$jusid AND liker=$liker` and `UPDATE junc_user_share SET likes=likes-1 WHERE id=$id`